# Update groovy 1.7.10 to groovy 2.2 including AST transform issue

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have to update my "groovy files" that have been written in 1.7 to 2.2. To be honest I'm kinda newbie with groovy so that's why I have simple question.

What should I care about when doing it and what exactly should I do? 
I simple installed 2.2 compiler in Eclipse and i got error about compiler mismatch but I handle this by switching to 2.2. I'm using JDK 6 and I'm also not sure about jdk version (I've read somewhere that groovy 2.2 needs jdk 7 to work correctly. Is it true?).

After compiling my projects i got multiple errors like this:

> Groovy:Unexpected problem with AST transform:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()Ljava/lang/String;

Sorry for my bad english and I hope you understand what I was askin for.

Comment: Groovy requires Java 1.5+.  The current statement is that this will not change until Groovy 3.0 is released.

Comment: thanks for that. I noticed that 3.0 will work with 1.8 but wasn't sure about 2.2.